# CSS Qualtrics HotSpot

Tags: javascript, css, qualtrics

For a psychology research project, we have to use "hot spot" question type in a qualtrics survey. When we click on a defined region, there is two default colors: green (like) and red (dyslike).

We would like to have the possibility to change these default colors (for example, black (like) and blue (dyslike) .

I tried these two css code lines without success:

```
*.Skin .HotSpot .Like .RegionInner .RegionInnerInner{background-color:black;filter:alpha(opacity=30);opacity:.3}*

*.Skin .HotSpot .Dislike .RegionInner .RegionInnerInner{background-color:blue;filter:alpha(opacity=30);opacity:.3}*
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: This is the link for the basic hot spot question type in Qualtrics. I used it to test the custom css code.  To facilitate the tests, I put only one central hot spot region above one picture.
https://toulousepsychology.eu.qualtrics.com/SE/?SID=SV_0uNxnecY1UozRNH
Like I said earlier, when we click on the hot spot region, there is only two default colors : green (like) and red (dyslike). And for experimental reasons, we need to change these default colors. :(

Answer (score 0):

To use the filter property your CSS code should be:

```
filter: opacity(30%);
```

Also, why do you have a filter of 30% and the opacity of .3? on the same elements. They both do the same thing.

If you have link then please do add it to the original question and I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Just adding to this answer, you can define colors with RGBA (red, green, blue, **alpha**) to avoid having to use the `opacity` property, which makes the entire element dimmer rather than only the background, which may or may not be what OP is asking for. Black with 30% background opacity is `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);`, for example.

Comment: Yes vladdobra I agree, particularly if there is a text element going to be sitting on the original div.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried this line but the result is the same. It seems it wasn’t the origin of the problem.
.Skin .HotSpot .Like .RegionInner .RegionInnerInner{background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);}